# PHP script spawning requests to itself in endless loop

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, magento, session

I'm not even sure if I'm describing this problem correctly. I think the main thing I want to know is how I can trace the source of these requests in the code.

The problem had occurred before and I "solved" it by adding a `deny` to `.htaccess` against the IP of the server itself.

The problem reoccurred suddenly and for no apparent reason. My `.htaccess` setting lost its magical protective power. No changes were made in the code. Around the time of the reccurrence, I changed a config setting to add a cookie domain. I tried changing it back to blank, and I tried deleting all session files (and Magento cache). If the sessions setting caused the recurrence, that should have fixed it but it didn't.

The only thing that "fixed" it was turning off the Magento setting for web server rewrites for "clean" urls along with commenting out this line in `.htacces`:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The site now "works", with ugly urls and, mysteriously, incredibly degraded performance. 10-20 seconds for pages to load that used to take 1-2. PHP and MySQL appear to function normally now.

But with original setting after the problem happened, I was seeing a bunch of PHP instances in `top` from the command line. MySQL `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shoeds an ever-increasing quantity of sleeping processes. And my Magento website's `session` folder continuously added new sessions (about 1 new session per second, even though my client browser IP address was the ONLY one allowed by htaccess during this test). 
From the browser on the client side, most requests time out, and rarely the page does load after a VERY long time (10+ minutes - PHP max_execution_time is long to allow for long import/export processes to complete).

A static `index.php` that just echoes "it works" loads without any weird errors.

I have no idea what the problem is. Is it malicious code? Is it some problem with session handling? Could it even be related to DNS? I could make progress solving the problem if I could trace the source of the "zombie" requests somehow.

EDIT: Here is my complete .htaccess file, with some things redacted ( I changed IP addresses)

```
############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 512M
 #   php_value max_execution_time 10
    php_value max_input_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized


    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Netscape 4.x has some problemsÂ~E
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# DonÂ~Rt compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies donÂ~Rt deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

# enable resulting html compression
#php_flag zlib.output_compression on

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

# if site is at raw ip/user url like http://111.22.33.44/~users_folder/
#   RewriteBase /~users_folder/
        RewriteBase /

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    #ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
        #try denying own ip. it seems like it is sending the requests!
        #this server ip e.g. 111.22.33.44
        # this hack "fixed" the problem a long time ago.
        Deny from 111.22.33.44

#       Order deny,allow
#       Deny from all
#       Allow from [particular IP for testing]

<FilesMatch "\.(?:inc|ini|txt|tar|gz|sql|sh|zip|htm|html|log)$|apc.php">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    FileETag none

Options All -Indexes

# 4 Weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|phtml)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|PNG|JPEG|GIF|SWF|JPG)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public"
</FilesMatch>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/phtml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/GIF "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/PNG "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/JPG "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/JPEG "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What else is in the .htaccess? That rule alone would always result in a redirect loop (which the web server will often detect and halt). It is typically prevented by preceding that with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` just before `RewriteRule .* index.php`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski those lines are there just before the rewrite rule, along with `!-l`. Could something be causing those `RewriteCond` directives to fail, resulting in a loop from the `RewriteRule`?

Comment: If your server is making requests to itself, I really have no idea. I don't know about Magento at all - just about mod_rewrite.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you. I added my complete `.htaccess` file. I don't even know if it is making requests to itself. That is just how I'm interpreting what I'm seeing ( all the mysql threads, all the sessions being created, and the fact that denying from the server's external IP "fixed" the problem temporarily).

Comment: The fact that echoing something in the index.php file fixes the issue makes me wonder if this is an issue with your Magento rewrites.  Back up the core_url_rewrite table and truncate it -- run a reindex and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @espradley The index.php file I mentioned was just a plain one I created to test response outside of magento. All it contained was `echo "It works"`. But I did try your suggestion about truncating and rebuilding the core_url_rewrite table. Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem.