# Create temporary redirect adding "index.php" into url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

If user requests this page:

```
example.com/asdf/jkl?qwer=ty
```

I want them redirected to

```
example.com/index.php/asdf/jkl?qwer=ty
```

I believe 307 is probably the appropriate status code.
I just need to add in "index.php" after the domain name for every request.
But... images on the page are still found at `example.com/image/asdf.jpg`. I don't know if an `.htaccess` directive would affect in-line resource requests or not, but I would need it not to.

The reason I need this is that we are having [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810929/php-script-spawning-requests-to-itself-in-endless-loop) with our site that is requiring us to add "index.php" into urls. Hopefully we can fix it soon. But meanwhile, our Google indexed search results are leading to 404 errors.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/index - [L] # stop rule processing if request already starts with "index.php"
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L,R]
```

Testing this on `example.com/asdf/jkl`, it results in `example.com/index.php/index.php/index.php/.../index.php/asdf/jkl` where "index.php" is repeated a bunch of times. Sometimes I also get a message about a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!index.php/).*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That seems to be working pretty well. I guess if I wanted to actually redirect I could change the end to `[L,NC,R=302]`

Comment: Yes if you want URL to change then use: `RewriteRule ^((?!index.php/).*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,R=302]`